# Can jquery-based sorting or loading, like isotope or infinite scroll have a negative effect on for SEO?

Tags: categories, filter, seo

I'm curious what the community thinking is on this point.  While infinite scrolling may present a user-friendly tool for listing a large number of entries, isn't there potentially a downside from an SEO perspective IF the content in question doesn't have its own single entry screen which would expose an SEO-friendly semantic URL?

For blogs posts, for example, a common URL structure might be domain.com/blog to list most recent entries and a single blog post might be domain.com/blog/comments/entry-utl-title.  EE then gives you a simple way to generate category-sorted lists using the category segment with something like domain.com/blog/category/category-url-title (and if you use addons you can also potentially achieve parenting segments, but not natively).  I have to assume that the category url titles themselves are good for SEO as well, all things being equal.

A suggestion I was given for filtering content on the front end - particularly around filtering content with combinations of categories or other entry data - was a jQuery plugin called Isotope (in place of using EE's native advanced search, for example).  It's a really interesting functionality for the user on the front end, but it got me thinking about the single-category-at-a-time URL structure I've often used.  With an EE implementation of something like the isotope jquery plugin to use tags to filter and sort your list, the category URLs, no longer exist, do they?  Or do you retain them as fallback if the user has javascript turned off?  I'm wondering if you are giving up something by going that route, or is the combination of list view and single entry view enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'proper' way to do this is to link as normal to single pages that show the entry detail but then use JS to hijack the link's target and pull in just the content via ajax.

I use the MX Ajax Detect add-on to make a single template respond differently (ie, returning a full page vs returning just chunks of content) depending on whether it was requested via ajax: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-ajax-detect

You can see this in action on this page: http://www.ceridian.co.uk/about - clicking on the faces makes an ajax request for the content, while search engine robots will still be able to index the href of the anchor tags, even though regular users will not arrive at those pages.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you wouldn't want your category, tag or archive pages being indexed anyway as it's much more important that the single-entry pages are the ones that are ranking, and also because you can run into duplicate content problems if some pages show exactly the same listing of posts.

As long as your isotoped or infinitely-scrolling pages link through to individual entry pages, I don't really see a problem.